# parse string containing comma in csv using mysql? (or maybe pandas?)

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm, csv, parsing

（I'm using mysql　v５.7）

I have a csv file that has something like

mytable1

```
 name   sys        id
name1 aaa,bbb,ccc 8,3,5 
name2 ccc,bbb     22,33
name3 ccc,ccc     11,56
name4 aaa,ccc,ccc,ccc 87,88,40,99
```

note that 'aaa,bbb,ccc' is one string and '8,3,5' is one string..
I know it's not a good practice putting data like this but this is what I have given from other department...
so my first task was to extract number matched with ccc.
like this:

mytable2

```
name  id
name1 5 
name2 22
name3 11
name4 88
```

for the name3, there were two 'ccc' but it is ok to pick the first one.

I could get the right result by doing

```
select sub.name,
case
when x = 0 then SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(sub.id, ",", 1),",",-1)
when x= 1 then SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(sub.id, ",", 2),",",-1)
when x=2 then SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(sub.id, ",", 3),",",-1)
when x=3 then SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(sub.id, ",", 4),",",-1)
when x=4 then SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(sub.id, ",", 5),",",-1)
else SUBSTRING_INDEX(sub.id, ",", -1)
end as y
 from (
SELECT DISTINCT
       mytable1.*,
case 
when SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(sys, ",", 1),",",-1) = 'ccc' then 0
when SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(sys, ",", 2),",",-1) = 'ccc' then 1
when SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(sys, ",", 3),",",-1) = 'ccc' then 2
when SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(sys, ",", 4),",",-1) = 'ccc' then 3
when SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(sys, ",", 5),",",-1) = 'ccc' then 4
else -1
end as x
FROM mytable1) sub
```

so basically, I found the index of the ccc then use that index to find the matched id. (btw max number of items in sys column is 6 like 'aaa, bbb, ccc, ccc, ccc, ccc')

now I am wondering if there's any way to find the ids that's from ccc but not included in the mytable2.
like this.

```
  56 40 99
```

any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: While there may be a solution for this in mysql, this sort of problem is best handled in an application language. SQL does structured query well, unstructured is best left to application languages.

Comment: right, I edited original post thanks for pointing out :) @Akina

Comment: Your version is too old and have no the possibilities which allows to solve your task effectively. Does some upper limit of separate values amount per column value exists?

Comment: I see. the upper limit per column is 6. @Akina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` matched the first specified `sys` may be found by simple

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(id, ',', FIND_IN_SET(@parameter, sys)), ',', -1) id
FROM mytable1
HAVING id > '';
```

For to extract all another values use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(id, ',', num), ',', -1) id
FROM mytable1
JOIN (SELECT 1 num UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) numbers
    ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(sys, ',', num), ',', -1) = @parameter
HAVING id NOT IN (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(id, ',', FIND_IN_SET(@parameter, sys)), ',', -1)
                  FROM mytable1);
```

You may remove `name` from the output if you do not need in it.

Increase the numbers count in `numbers` subquery accordingly if the `sys`/`id` value may contain more than 4 separate values in CSV.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3e90b0b7f97780a1d3469071f40857e9)